# How do I format Tile View JSON so that it doesn't break apart a word in the middle of the word for multi line column

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, json-formatting, multiline-text-field, view-formatting

I have created a tile view that has a few columns from a SharePoint list. I have everything formatted perfectly, except it randomly breaks apart lines in the middle of a word.

Say `teacher` it would be. Am I missing something?

Picture of how its breaking up text:

[image: picture of how its breaking up text]

Picture of JSON:

[image: picture of JSON]

Picture of revised JSON but now it doesnt display all the lines only the first line [image: edited json]

Answer (score 0):

I think below CSS style applied to `div` element in your JSON is breaking the words in middle:

```
"white-space": "normal"
```

**Documentation**:

1. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)
2. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: I tried removing that line and nothing seemed to change. is there some reason that nothing for "style" is effecting that one area?

Comment: Is this SharePoint default "Gallery" view? Did you write all JSON all by yourself or customized the auto-generated JSON in gallery view?

Comment: customized the Auto Generated one from Sharepoint

Comment: so i tried restarting from scratch and this is what I get, but then it doesnt show all the lines for the comments in the multi line column - see the question above for updated screenshot

Comment: @Theresa   Have you tried using these two CSS properties:  word-break: break-word  and  overflow-y: visible ?